# Window.open() Set focus by FrameName

Tags: safari, focus, window.open

I want to give my users an *App* experience, so I'm trying to control tabs.
**In Safari** I notice that opening a new tab using a FrameName that is already open does not result in that window gaining focus.

I've figured out a workaround, but it feels very *hacky*.

```
function openNewTab(tabUrl, tabName) {
    var myWindow = window.open('', tabName); //open an empty named tab
    myWindow.close(); //close it
    window.open(tabUrl, tabName); //open a NEW tab rather than loading into an existing tab
}
```

Does anybody have a better approach?